# Replacing and animating icon in fontawesome SVG

Tags: jquery, svg, font-awesome-5

Before I switched to FA SVG the job of swapping an icon was quite simple -- remove old class, add two new ones. With SVG things are a bit more complex and while I was able to swap the icon I am not able to animate it...

**HTML**

```
<span id="myButton" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="fas fa-check fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Click me
</span>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", "#myButton", function() {
    $(this).find("svg").attr("data-icon", "spinner").removeClass("fa-check").addClass("fa-spinner disabled");
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: in order to change a data attribute  i would suggest to use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

In any case your issue is related to a class you forgot to add: **fa-spin**.

Instead of add and remove classes I would suggest to use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#myButton", function(e) {
    var svg = $(this).find("svg");
    var newIcon = svg.data("icon") == 'check' ? 'spinner' : 'check';
    svg.data("icon", newIcon).toggleClass("fa-check fa-spinner fa-spin disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>


<span id="myButton" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="fas fa-check fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Click me
</span>
```